# How to increase laptop/notebook USB voltage?

Tags: usb, voltage, usb-hub, defective-hardware, undervolting

USB ports typically provide anywhere between 5-6V.
If a laptop/notebook USB port is only producing between 4-5V;
What can be done to fix (i.e. boost/increase) the output voltage?

Comment: Replace the motherboard

Comment: @tjt263 - To what purpose  ?  The USB port seems to be operating within spec (USB does not go to 6 volts).  If you have a USB device which is drawing to much power you need to fix the power issue for that device (I'm thinking along the lines of a USB hub pulling more then 0.5 amps - eg to spin a hard drive).  In the case of something drawing more then 0.5 amps you need to supplement the power supply for that device.  (Sometimes a Y cable can do this, otherwise the correct way would be with appropriate hardware which can take an additional source of power from the wall)

Comment: *To what purpose? The USB port seems to be operating within spec.* It's not. Otherwise; it wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your measurements are too vague, they need to be more precise to determine if there is really an issue. You can't adjust the voltages, if there is a problem with the voltages it is a chipset issue and the motherboard in the laptop probably needs to be replaced. USB has very specific voltage ranges:

USB 2.0 - 5.0vDC +0.25/-0.60 @ 500ma load
USB 3.0 - 5.0vDC +0.25/-0.55 @ 900ma load

It is specified that devices configuration and low-power functions must operate down to 4.40 V at the hub port by USB 2.0 and that devices' configuration, low-power, and high-power functions must operate down to 4.00 V at the device port by USB 3.0.

More details on USB specifications are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power)

Comment: *Your measurements are too vague, they need to be more precise to determine if there is really an issue.* Well, I'm telling you outright; it's an issue. FYI: Pretty sure it's only USB 1.x but yeah, it does definitely get below ~4.40V. Although, my other laptop's bus produces output in excess of ~5.25V (up to ~5.69V) and my 5W iPad charger is currently peaking @ (actually seems to be fluctuating between) ~5.40V / ~5.44V.